# Campo input type="text" não preenche dados com mais de uma palavra

Tags: php, html, html5

Ao carregar um dado em um input somente a primeira palavra é carregada.
Exemplo:

```
'</form> <input type="text" value='.$result->name.' >';
```

`$result->name` contém o valor "Ola Mundo". Sendo que o input só mostra "Ola".

Alguém pode ajudar nisso?

Comment: Se fizeres `echo $result->name;` o que dá?

Comment: adicione no input um ID, e pode testar, document.getElementById('inputText').value = <?php $result->name ?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que o problema seja a falta de aspas no **value=""**, ele está tratando a palavra "Mundo" como se fosse um atributo do campo texto, ou seja a sua saida deve ser: `<input type="text" value=Ola Mundo>`, para resolver isso, você precisa colocar as aspas:

```
'</form>'."<input type=\"text\" value=\"{$result->name}\">";
```

Também pode fazer assim:

```
'</form><input type="text" value="'.$result->name.'">';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" value="'.$result->name.'">
```

adicione (")

ou

```
document.getElementById('inputText').value = <?php $result->name ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o atributo **maxlength** e ponha aspas no value:

```
'</form> <input type="text" maxlength="100" value="'.$result->name.' ">';
```

Comment: Foi isso mesmo! Pequenas coisas que agarram a gente ;) Obrigado.